# Printing numbers as long as an empty input is not entered

Tags: python, io, output

If I'm asking for a user input of numbers which continues as long as an empty string is not entered, if an empty string is entered then the program ends.
My current code is:

```
n=0
while n !=  "":
    n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

But obviously this isn't exactly what I want. I could remove the int input and leave it as a regular input, but this will allow all types of inputs and i just want numbers.
Do i ago about this a different way?

Comment: in short - yes, you need another approach. First, read the input to some variable, then check if it is integer (and decide what to do if it is not), if it was int - set the continue flag to True, if empty list set to False (you still need to make a decision what to do with non-empty non-int)

Comment: Your program isn't ending because the user is entering an empty string, per se. It's ending because you are not catching the `ValueError` that happens whenever something non-numeric is entered. Your `while` condition is totally spurious because `int()` will **never** return the empty string, or any string at all.

Answer (score 1):

calling `int()` on an empty string will cause a `ValueError` so you can encapsulate everything in a try block:

```
>>> while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('NUMBER: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Not an integer.')
        break


NUMBER: 5
NUMBER: 12
NUMBER: 64
NUMBER: 
not a number.
```

this also has the added benefit of catching anything ELSE that isn't an int.

Comment: Be careful with the 'number'/'not a number' language using an `int()` test. For example, this will insist that `'3.2'` is "not a number".

Comment: notice i said `anything else that isn't an INT` but yes, that is a good point

Comment: Yes, of course. Your explanation is correct, but the text of the program is misleading. :)

Comment: edited with a special shoutout, just for you @Two-BitAlchemist

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a try/except here instead.

Also, with using a try/except, you can instead change your loop to using a `while True`. Then you can use `break` once an invalid input is found.

Also, your solution is not outputting anything either, so you might want to set up a `print` statement after you get the input.

Here is an example of how you can put all that together and test that an integer is entered only:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        print(n)
    except ValueError:
        print("You did not enter a number")
        break
```

If you want to go a step further, and handle numbers with decimals as well, you can try to cast to float instead:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = float(input("Enter a number: "))
        print(n)
    except ValueError:
        print("You did not enter a number")
        break
```

Comment: OP wants to keep asking for a number until a blank is entered, so the other way around than from what you did.

Comment: The OP wants to stop when the user enters an empty string

Comment: I just noticed that. Thanks @RNar